# FlatButton margin changed after a Flutter Upgrade

Tags: flutter

I have run a Flutter Upgrade and it has caused a regression on one of my Layout.

Here is the code:

```
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          FlatButton(
            child: Icon(
              Icons.remove,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                if (_debitValue > 1) _debitValue--;
              });
            },
          ),

          Slider(
            value: _debitValue.toDouble(),
            min: 1.0,
            max: 100.0,
            onChanged: (double value) {
              setState(() {
                _debitValue = value.toInt();
              });
            },
          ),

          FlatButton(
            child: Icon(
              Icons.add,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                if (_debitValue <100) _debitValue++;
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

This is a row with a '-' button, then a slider, then a '+' button.

It was displayed fine. Yesterday I have done a Flutter Upgrade and it now exceeds the width of the screen by 8 pixels. It says:

```
I/flutter (13431): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (13431): The following message was thrown during layout:
I/flutter (13431): A RenderFlex overflowed by 8.0 pixels on the right.
I/flutter (13431): 
I/flutter (13431): The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.horizontal.
I/flutter (13431): The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and
I/flutter (13431): black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.
I/flutter (13431): Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the
I/flutter (13431): RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
I/flutter (13431): This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be
I/flutter (13431): seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a
I/flutter (13431): ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex,
I/flutter (13431): like a ListView.
```

I have added some colors to see the margins used by the FlatButtons. They look pretty big. I have tried to change them but I didn't succeed. I have tried:

```
FlatButton(materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap, ...)
```

I have seen that I can use an Inkwell instead of a FlatButton. It works but the effect on the button is different and I would like to understand how to do it with a FlatButton.

Thanks for your advices

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it but maybe something like this could work?

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: FlatButton(
        ...,
      ),
      flex: 1,
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Slider(
        ...,
      ),
      flex: 4, //maybe play with this value to see what looks best
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: FlatButton(
        ...,
      ),
      flex: 1,
    ),
  ],
),
```